# SQL: Real Transpose

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, transpose

I know about pivot and unpivot. That is not what I want. Pivot and unpivot aggregate data, but that is not what I want.

Think of a table as a matrix (linear algebra). If I start with an m x n matrix, I want to convert that matrix (table) into an n x m matrix. I want a true [TRANSPOSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose).

How can I do this in SQL?

For example if I have:

```
1  2  3
1  2  4
6  7  8
3  2  1
3  9  1
```

then the result should be:

```
1  1  6  3  3
2  2  7  2  9
3  4  8  1  1
```

Notice that the number of rows becomes the number of columns, and vice versa. Also notice that I have not grouped or aggregated any of the data. Every single value present in the source is present in the result, and their x-y coordinates have been swapped.

Comment: can you post some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server 2008. More details have been posted.

Comment: @mtmurdock is there a reason why you think a `PIVOT` will not work?

Comment: I know pivot wont work because this is not how pivot works. If you can show me a pivot that will do this, by all means. But I'm 90% certain it can't be done.

Comment: I am not sure why this was closed as not a question. It seems pretty straight-forward to me. How do I transpose data is SQL? There is even an answer that has multiple up-votes and it solved my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple way to transpose columns and rows in Sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am unsure why you think you cannot accomplish this with an `UNPIVOT` and a `PIVOT`:

```
select [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
from 
(
  select *
  from
  (
    select col1, col2, col3,
      row_number() over(order by col1) rn
    from yourtable
  ) x
  unpivot
  (
    val for col in (col1, col2, col3)
  ) u
) x1
pivot
(
  max(val)
  for rn in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed3ea/9).  This could also be performed dynamically if needed.

Edit, if the column order needs to be kept, then you can use something like this, which applies the `row_number()` without using a `order by` on one of the columns in your table (here is an [article about using non-deterministic row numbers](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/nondeterministic-row-numbers)):

```
select [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
from 
(
  select *
  from
  (
    select col1, col2, col3,
      row_number() 
        over(order by (select 1)) rn
    from yourtable
  ) x
  unpivot
  (
    val for col in (col1, col2, col3)
  ) u
) x1
pivot
(
  max(val)
  for rn in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
) p;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed3ea/23)

Comment: Wow this is REALLY close. Well done. The only issue is that you have reordered the columns when you used `order by col1` in your over clause. Any way to preserve the order?

Comment: @mtmurdock do you happen to have an `id` field on the table that places the rows in that order? Like a date or something?

Comment: Ok this looks great! I have no idea what its doing, but good work. I never thought to combine an unpivot and a pivot. I'm having a little trouble adapting it, but this should put me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm looking at your edit about preserving column order, but I don't understand what this is doing. It does not appear to be working for me.

Comment: @mtmurdock an `ORDER BY` is required in the `over()` but you do not want to order by any of the columns so you need to provide it will something either - `select 1` or even `select 0`. If you are having issues figuring it out, start with the inner query first to look at the `row_number()` then start working out

Comment: How does the row number impact the column order?

Comment: @mtmurdock it doesn't that is the point of the `select 1`, it is adding the `row_number()` for the `PIVOT`

Comment: I find that the second does preserve column order, but not row order. My rows (previously columns) are now being sorted by alphabetical order... Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Josh can you post a sql fiddle with a sample of your issue?